# printf issues in bash

Tags: bash, printf

OK, here's the code

```
printf "%0.s1" $(seq $1)
```

Simple enough, it sits in a function and you pass in a length and it gives you a bunch of 1s.  This function then pads 0s to create a string of 32 bits which another function changes to an integer or IP.  For example:

```
cdr2mask() {
    local BIMASK=$(printf "%-32s" $(printf "%0.s1" $(seq $1)) | tr ' ' '0')
    integerToIP $(convertbaseNumFromTo $BIMASK 2 10)
}
```

This function works fine when called directly (argument is the number of bits in your netmask, ex: 24).  But, when called from the following, it fails.  It gives a 1 followed by 31 0s instead of the correct mask.  It gets $1 correctly.  I've narrowed it down to the printf statement (the one at the top) only returning a single 1 when called this way.  The function calling cdr2mask is:

```
ipInNetwork() {
    local IFS HOST NETWORK NETMASK CIDR
    read HOST NETWORK NETMASK <<<$*
    if [ -z "$NETMASK" ]; then
        IFS='/'
        read NETWORK CIDR <<<"$NETWORK"
        if [ -z "$CIDR" ]; then
            NETMASK="255.255.255.255"
        else
            NETMASK=$( cdr2mask "$CIDR" )
        fi
    fi
    if [ $(( $( ipToInteger $HOST ) & $( ipToInteger $NETMASK ) )) = \
    $(( $( ipToInteger $NETWORK ) & $( ipToInteger $NETMASK ) )) ]; then
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
    fi
}
```

The following versions of cdr2mask work fine, so its not the caller:

```
newcdr2mask() {
    local ONES="11111111111111111111111111111111"
    local BINUM=$(printf "%-32s" ${ONES:0:$1} | tr ' ' 0)
    integerToIP $( convertbaseNumFromTo $BINUM 2 10 )
}

oldcdr2mask () 
{
   # Number of args to shift, 255..255, first non-255 byte, zeroes
   set -- $(( 5 - ($1 / 8) )) 255 255 255 255 $(( (255 << (8 - ($1 % 8))) & 255 )) 0 0 0
   [ $1 -gt 1 ] && shift $1 || shift
   echo ${1-0}.${2-0}.${3-0}.${4-0}
}
```

The last one I didn't write.  Of course, suggestions on speed improvements and other suggestions are welcome.  I'm not getting the speed I really want here, but I'm only just starting to optimize.  The "old" method may still be the fastest, but I want to get the other version working so I can test it.  Could this be a bash bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit:

```
IFS='/'
```

This breaks the `seq` expansion - `seq` outputs newlines as separators (by default), and the shell doesn't do word splitting on those when `IFS` is `/`. (`local IFS` doesn't help here, local variables are visible in the called functions.)

I'd avoid setting IFS entirely, by doing something like this instead of the `read`:

```
CIDR=${NETWORK##*/}
NETWORK=${NETWORK%/*}
```

(With a `case` statement to deal with the cases for `NETWORK` containing a `/` or not.)

Comment: Makes sense!  Would a case really be better than the [ -z line?

Comment: `[ -z` on CIDR won't work with what I posted above. If NETWORK doesn't have a `/`, my substitutions would both be no-ops, i.e. return NETWORK unchanged in CIDR and NETWORK.

Comment: Oh OK, that code doesn't give the CIDR part if there isn't a slash, it just returns the whole thing instead of an empty string.  Hmm ... that requires more code changes than just resetting IFS in the called function.  Apparently local is inherited by subfunctions and not actually "local", so resetting it when needed is a quicker fix.

Comment: If you prefer to continue playing with IFS (I hate doing that), just reset it right after the read so it doesn't "infect" other functions.

Comment: We posted at the same time.  Swapping IFS works, but the double-printf method was the slowest way to do it, next in line was a single printf that took a substring of 1s and padded it with zeros.  The fastest was the unreadable one that I didn't write.  I didn't want to move to a "case" as the extra regex was a slight bit slower than the if statement, but it allowed me to optimize the most common netmask cases by pre-computing them.  That drops run time down to 60% of what was before, so the case was worth it.  Thanks!

Comment: One more side note for other readers.  I just remembered that "read" supports passing the delimiter (-d) instead of modifying IFS.  It looks like changing IFS is "bad", so use -d instead.

Comment: Bash's `read`'s `-d` isn't what you're looking for, it's a delimiter for the "end of line".